# Dynamic Link in UFT automation?

Tags: vbscript, automation, hp-uft

I want to write a dynamic VBScript for my web automation in UFT 12.02. I would like to pass a dynamic value as part of the link. here is my sample Line code:

```
set ObjExcel = CreateObject("Excel.application")
ObjExcel.workbooks.open "F:\Automation\Web\Business\WebTestData.xls"

For Curr= 1 To 20
    USD = ObjExcel.sheets(1).cells(Curr,1).Value
    If Browser("...").Page("...").Exist Then
       Browser("...").Page("...").WebElement("WebElement").Click
       'Attempt to click on Drop Down Link
       Browser("...").Page("...").Link("USD").Click
    End If
Next
```

`"USD"` will keep changing, i.e. I will be picking it from Excel.

**Expected Result:**

Generate a script that will attempt to click on different links as below:

```
Browser("...").Page("...").Link("EURO").Click
Browser("...").Page("...").Link("BP").Click
Browser("...").Page("...").Link("AED").Click
Browser("...").Page("...").Link("KSH").Click
Browser("...").Page("...").Link("IR").Click
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should use USD without double quote.

```
Dim currType, ObjExcel

set ObjExcel = CreateObject("Excel.application")
ObjExcel.workbooks.open "F:\Automation\Web\Business\WebTestData.xls"

For Curr= 1 To 20
   currType = ObjExcel.sheets(1).cells(Curr,1).Value
   If Browser("...").Page("...").Exist Then
      Browser("...").Page("...").WebElement("WebElement").Click
      'Attempt to click on Drop Down Link
      Browser("...").Page("...").Link(currType).Click
   End If
Next

set ObjExcel = Nothing
```

Note: I've changed USD with currType.

Answer (score 1):

I have zero experience with UFT, but shouldn't using the *variable* `USD` instead of the *string* `"USD"` do what you want?

```vb
For Curr= 1 To 20
  USD = ObjExcel.sheets(1).cells(Curr,1).Value
  If Browser("...").Page("...").Exist Then
    Browser("...").Page("...").WebElement("WebElement").Click
    'Attempt to click on Drop Down Link
    Browser("...").Page("...").Link(USD).Click
  End If
Next
```